# How to format a comment?

Tags: support, comments, formatting

Eg in [this post](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/473/0-accept-rate-doesnt-display)'s comment Kirk has formatted the URLs nicely:

> @whuber Note that this users' [first question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6848/develop-gui-in-python-for-geoprocessing) is Mar 7. I agree that we
>   shouldn't display 0% when someone asks their first question, but at
>   some point there needs to be [acceptance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance)

How is that done? I tried adding `<a href...>` tags in a comment but just saw `"<a href...>"`  in the comment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is *no* HTML allowed in comments. Some Markdown is available however...

Next time you're writing a comment, click the little *help* link under the big Add Comment button. Then click [learn more...](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to learn more than you probably wanted to know.

Comment: **thanks** a _bunch_ this is great

Comment: +1 @StephenLead, I _fully_ [agree with you](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/597/how-to-format-a-comment#comment931_598) heh `:)`